# Is there any way to import easydict in anaconda on windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection

I am working on a research of **"Object Detection" with faster-RCNN**. I have cloned the project from **https://github.com/endernewton/tf-faster-rcnn** . After importing the project into **anaconda spyder** I ran the **demo.py** file. But I get an **import error.**

> "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'easydict'"

Can it be fixed on windows 10?

Comment: From an anaconda terminal, activate your environment, and run `pip install easydict`. IIUC, this should be platform-independent; that said, I've only just tested it on Ubuntu.

Comment: It throws exceptions

Comment: please tell me the process details.

Comment: When you run `pip install easydict`, what exceptions are thrown?

Comment: There are so many exceptions like
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tonu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
File "C:\Users\Tonu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
File "C:\Users\Tonu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
 File "C:\Users\Tonu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes

Answer (score 1):

easydict is a module which is currently not offered throught the default standard conda channel. Instead, you can use e.g. the conda-forge channel:

```
conda install easydict -c conda-forge
```

Comment: I installed by conda.... but in pip, there is no easydict(also in python, can not be pip import easydict --> no module easydict)